# Advanced search results view mode

Tags: magento

Does anyone know how to change the view mode of the advanced search results in Magento? Standard is list mode, i prefer grid mode though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `setListCollection('grid')` in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch\advanced\result.phtml`

[docs](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_CatalogSearch/Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result.html#getProductListHtml)

or replace

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

with ( comment out ) in catalogsearch.xml from layout folder

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>  
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>  
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>  
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>  
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
```

Comment: From what i see now the problem is slightly different. Each item got his own unordered list what I think is the problem. Normal search results going well though. How is this possible?

Comment: why don't you modify with css?

Comment: That is possible but not the ideal solution. I will modify the CSS for now.

Comment: Michael, the development manifesto says "do it now, modify later". As a result, make site to work properly, at the end, if you have time, just modify ugly parts!